# Story in which two brothers had to follow extremely detailed instructions to get their inheritance

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I recall reading a short story a number of years ago where two brothers were each given extremely detailed (and sometimes rather tedious) instructions that they had to follow very precisely in order to get their inheritance. One of the brothers ended up having to spend a lot of the night in a tower, periodically going to the top at very exact times in order to get his next set of instructions and then returning to the bottom of the tower. At one point, he almost fell asleep and missed one of the deadlines IIRC.

I don't recall the exact details of the other brother's instructions, but he had to go all over town in order to accomplish all of them. The story focused primary on that brother.

One brother (I think the one in the tower) just barely finished his entire set of instructions on time, having only a few minutes to spare.

I think (but am not 100% sure) that the story was originally written in English. The story may have been written by O. Henry, but I'm not sure of that either.

Can anyone help me identify this story?